# POST datas not passing Laravel 4

Tags: php, post, get, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm currently tutoring myself on Laravel 4 and I encounter a strange problem:

I have a blade form:

```
<form action="{{url('/')}}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="baz" value="boo"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

and a Route:

```
Route::any('/', function()
{
    $data = Input::all();
    var_dump($data);
});

Route::get('post-form',function()
{
    return View::make('form');
});
```

If I use Get instead of Post (in the blade form) everything's running perfectly but when I try to use Post the returned array is empty

Any clues ? :)
(forgive my English since i'm french native)

Comment: What if you try to not use '/'? I remember there being problems with using the root path URL for POST routes.

Comment: That made the trick :) without using the root everything is running perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

try to use `Route::post` instead of `Route::any` and dd instead of var_dump

```
Route::post('/', function()
{
    $data = Input::all();
    dd($data);
});
```

**Edit:**
you have a little mistake in your html form:

```
<form action="{{url('/')}}" method="POST">
```

it should look like this:

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
```

I hope it will work this time

Comment: When I try to change only the method by post I have a "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." and the "dd" doesn't change anything sadly :/ but thx for your concern :)

Comment: It's a Blade form not a pure HTML so I have to use this synthax to obtain the absolut path, and the problem seems to come from the root itself as @Andreas said :)

Comment: you can use html only but if you want to use blade it is better to open your form using blade: {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'route.name')) }} and then your route should be a named route

Comment: Thx for those détails :) I'll be using them :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code out and it works perfectly. There is no problem with it.
I suggest you using `Route::post` when you are sure sending `POST` data

Comment: That's why it seemed to be a strange problem since the code appeared to be clean. Avoiding using the root made the trick for now but maybe I must take a look at the Project config to avoid this problem in the future and understand what happened :)